# Fullscreen how to block hot corners

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, fullscreen, quartz-2d

How to block hot corners when game is in fullscreen?
When hot corners are enable in system, and game is in fullscreen, when i move cursor to any corner game is minimalize.

I change to fullscreen like this:

```
fullscreenWindow = [[NSWindowFullscreen alloc] initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];
mainWindow = [self window];
[mainWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:NO];
[mainWindow orderOut:nil];

// Set the options for our new fullscreen window     
[fullscreenWindow setReleasedWhenClosed: YES];
[fullscreenWindow setLevel: NSFloatingWindowLevel];
[fullscreenWindow setHidesOnDeactivate:YES];            
[fullscreenWindow setContentView: self];
[fullscreenWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];    
[fullscreenWindow makeFirstResponder:self];         
[fullscreenWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

The mouse position you can change when mouse position on top.

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
    {
        NSPoint mouseLoc;
        mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation]; //get current mouse position
        //mouse position change
        CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
        int Height = (int)ScrnRect.size.height;
       // NSLog(@"Height::%d,MouSe.Y::%f",Height,mouseLoc.y);
        if(Height < mouseLoc.y+5 ){
            CGEventRef mouse = CGEventCreateMouseEvent (NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved, CGPointMake( mouseLoc.x, 5), 0);
            CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, mouse);
            CFRelease(mouse);
            CFRelease(source);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a higher level in **setLevel:**
You are not restricted to the ones in NSWindow Class Reference.
Those are just other names done by #define for a subset of the ones in Quartz/Core Graphics.
See them in the **Constants** 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html